# App that shows available SSL protocols and ciphers for HTTPS handshake

Tags: android, ssl

I'm looking for an Android app that shows what protocols (SSL 2.0, TLS 1.2 etc) and what [cipher suites](https://testssl.sh/openssl-rfc.mappping.html) are available for a https: connection to a server.

Like what Qualys [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) does when analyzing a server connection.

I want to use this for testing my server software - I'm limiting the available protocols and ciphers and want to check if that actually works. Setting up a server with an outside connection is too cumbersome, I want to test the connection to my software running at an address like 192.168.0.72:8888

Plus points if the app does not require needless permissions.
Free would be nice.

I have seen the following:

- A '[OpenSSL checker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.foosys.osslchk)' but can't test what it does without paying for it.
- [SSLTestTool](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.aseemsethi.sslTestTool) has a very unclear interface (*What is it doing?*) and insist on connecting to www.google.com despite me changing the *Server* setting.
- [Home network SSL checker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.inka.bigred.homenetchecker&hl=en) seems to check only certificates

Comment: Not tested myself, but might be worth a look: [Network Debug](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nicolasb1.network.debug)